# Separator in ItemsControl renders in different shades for each item

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, separator

I have an ItemsControl presenting TextBlocks, with a Separator at the bottom of each item.

My problem is that each Separator is rendered in a slightly different shade of gray - it looks really dodgy:

[image]

Here is my XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" ></TextBlock>
                <Separator></Separator>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have also tried using a thin border instead of the Separator, with the same result.

How can I make each line identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```

If this doesn't help you can also try with

- [`UseLayoutRounding="True"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding.aspx) (WPF 4)
- [`RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.edgemode.aspx) (Turn of anti-aliasing)