# Image renders differently depending on position

Tags: wpf, image, rendering

I have an ItemsControl presenting a list of buttons.  Each button has an image as it's content (png), but the image looks slightly different for each row.

The below image is magnified version of what I'm seeing:
[image]

Here is the xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel   Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Name="tb1">hello</TextBlock>
                <Button Height="{Binding ElementName=tb1, Path=ActualHeight}" Padding="0,-3,-3,-3" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" >
                    <Image Stretch="Fill"  Source="stock_standard_filter.png" Margin="0">
                    </Image>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I've had a [similar issue previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5255071/503969) and was able to solve it using `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`, but that solution is not working this time.  I've also tried `UseLayoutRounding="True"` and `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"`

Comment: what happens if you try Stretch="None" ?

Comment: @blindmeis: It still renders differently, but even worse is that the image is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the button is bound so the image will be stretched to fill the button. Because WPF uses doubles (1/96 inch units) there is bound to be some rounding off. SnapsToDevicePixels and Layout rounding might help when you use them on the StackPanel but as long as you stretch the image it will get blurred.

My best guess is to set "Stretch to None" and experiment with SnapsToDevicePixels and Layout rounding.